# How do I target arm64 on a net7.0-macos project?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, arm64, multitargeting

I'm building a multi targeted app with frameworks `net7.0-windows;net7.0-macos`.

When I build the project, it is building to `bin/Debug/net7.0-macos/osx-x64`.

I'd like for it to target arm64 since I'm on an M1 mac.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With .NET Core, you don't need to target a specific architecture, you just deploy for it, using e.g.

```
dotnet publish MyProject.csproj --runtime linux-arm64
```

This will create the bin/Debug/net7.0/publish folder with the project prepared for arm64.

*However*, that will most likely result in an error if your project targets `net7.0-windows;net7.0-macos`. You need to have a generic target specifier such as only `net7.0`. The operating-system specific targets `net7.0-windows` and `net7.0-macos` are only required if you use libraries that are only available for these frameworks, such as WPF or WinForms. Since you already target macos, I doubt you're using any of these, so why aren't you just using the generic `net7.0` target?

Comment: The goal was to have separate builds for separate OS platforms as they have different platform specific dependencies, and I only wanted to include those dependencies for the specific platform build. But I think I'm overcomplicating things for now :)

Comment: Yes, that may make things more complicated (for everybody, including the users of your tool/library). It's usually easier to go with one build and do, where required, run-time OS checks.